# Why is Javascript returning [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#sign_up").on('click', function() {
    $.post('./includes/ajax.php', { action: 'register' } , function(result) {
      var result = JSON.parse(result);
        if(result ) { $("#register_result") = result; document.write(result); }
    });
  });
$("#register_form").submit(function() {
  return false;
});
</script>
```

In the console it's returning "All inputs must be entered" - which is what I want it to return.

However, the alert is returning [object Object].  Why is this?

Comment: [Don't use `alert()` for debugging](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)

Answer (score 10):

`console.log` will give you a debugging view of an object.

`alert` will give you a string view of an object.

Objects are converted to strings by calling `.toString()` on them.

The default `toString()` function on a basic object will return `"[Object object]"`

Comment: I edited the original question check my comment on Ancarius' answer.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it seems you're trying to get JSON data back. If that's the case why not simply set dataType (the 4th parameter in the $.post function to 'json')?

Also JSON is an object and alert isn't really good at returning objects. If you're looking to debug your code, might I suggest using `console.log(result)`? It's much more informative and less intrusive.

Comment: It's already logging it in the console and I want it to be displayed to the user.  I will change the alert();  I edited the original question, how can I have it write to #register_result so that the user can see it say "All inputs must be entered"?

Comment: @JohnSmith `document.write()` has the same "problem" as `alert()` as described by Quentin. You need to print the object to the console so that you'll see which element contains the message you want to print and print that (`document.write( result.msg )` for example if the message happens to be in element `msg`).

Comment: @JohnSmith Since you're going with jQuery, you can use <code>$('#register_result').html(result.msg);</code> described [here](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2 "jQuery API .html()"). While the content returned in the AJAX response is an object, the end elements should be parsable text.